# why can't i open a link inside the ui of my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-widget

I'm new to flutter, and I'm developing an android app for my company that shows their projects and the offers they make, the name of the app is "Dhakay" and it's available on play store
my problem is that I wanna display an internal link inside the app, the thing is when I make the link open in a navigator(outside the UI of the app) it opens normally
but when I do make it open inside the UI it shows "unauthorized"[what I get when I try to open the link inside the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYfc4.png)
[when I make it open inside the navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvWJ0.png)
[after authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOhV.png)
could anyone help me, please?
`SimpleFoldingCell.create( key: _foldingCellKey1, frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget( _foldingCellKey1, "assets/iot-banner.png", S.current.gas_monitoring, "http://gatech.amenhyd.com:1880/ui",true), innerWidget: _buildInnerWidget( _foldingCellKey1, "assets/iot-banner.png", S.current.details, S.current.details_sonelgaz2, "http://gatech.amenhyd.com:1880/ui",true), cellSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 140), padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), borderRadius: 5, ), );`

Comment: I didn't catch your question, you want to open a link inside your app? anyway unauthorized means you need to send a username or password or everything you need for authorization

Comment: when i open the link in browser, it asks me to enter password and username, but when i open it inside the app it just shows me "unauthorized"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the port you're trying to access requires to be connected to a Private network or a Local network. usually when you're calling an endpoint you can pass authorization tokens or any required params in header.
You can ask your website admin about the authorizations required to access the link. and then it'll work inside your Flutter app as well.

Comment: but it opens from my navigator normally, why does it require authoizations when i open it inside the app!?

Comment: @NawfelBoutabia Try to open using [flutter webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and see if it works.

Comment: i am already using it brother, same result